# Android Canvas Drawing Inconsistency

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I have an ImageView subclass that is supposed to display a logo in the bottom corner of the displayed image. I have this onDraw code to draw the icon on top of the image. It works fine on ICS+ but nothing lower. Does anyone know the reason for this?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
    int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();

    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.icon);

    int width = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = iconcon.getIntrinsicHeight();

    int x = canvasWidth - width - PADDING;
    int y = canvasHeight - height - PADDING;

    icon.setBounds(x, y, canvasWidth - PADDING, canvasHeight - PADDING);
    icon.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: so on lower version does it gives any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to ignore `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` and use the values received in `onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)` instead, because sometimes they don't match and `canvas.getWidth()/getHeight()` gives strange results.